# fs.copySync is not a function when building react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, electron

I'm trying to package my Electron-react app but I have some issues.

I use that line to compile :
`"electron:package:mac": "npm build && electron-builder -m -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js",`

Electron builder told me first that there was no app.asar so I have checked what did it make when I build react alone.

I got that :

```
Failed to compile.

fs.copySync is not a function


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sendinblue@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sendinblue@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above
```

But when I check the complete log I have this :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle sendinblue@0.1.0~prebuild: sendinblue@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle sendinblue@0.1.0~build: sendinblue@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle sendinblue@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle sendinblue@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/XXX/Documents/MacBookPro/projects/sendinblue/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
9 verbose lifecycle sendinblue@0.1.0~build: CWD: /Users/XXX/Documents/MacBookPro/projects/sendinblue
10 silly lifecycle sendinblue@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle sendinblue@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle sendinblue@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: sendinblue@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid sendinblue@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/XXX/Documents/MacBookPro/projects/sendinblue
16 verbose Darwin 20.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.17.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.13
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error sendinblue@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the sendinblue@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I don't understand anything, issues have no linked with each others …
Does anybody could help me ?
Thanks